# How can I change database values in Javascript code, but not allow the user to change (or access) database values in the Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, so I'm creating a web app.

The web app basically is a game, in which you have a number of points. You get more points by answering addition questions correctly.

I'm using Firebase Real-time Database to save the users' score. This is the code I'm running whenever the user answers a question correctly: (`document.getElementById("score").innerText` is the current score)

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
   score: parseInt(document.getElementById("score").innerText) + 2,
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

So that works fine. But, I found out, that a user could take that code, and put it in the console and gain infinite points.

So how would I go about fixing this? This is my current database rules if that needs to be changed:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

My more generalized question is

> How can I change database values in Javascript code, but not allow the user to change (or access) database values in the Javascript console?

I looked into https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data and couldn't find anything helpful. I think I need to change something in the database rules.

UPDATE: The best solution suggested so far was to use Cloud Functions in Firebase.

Comment: Tip: begging people not to downvote tends to *generate* downvotes here. I've removed that paragraph.

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion @ceejayoz :) These are the members of the community I like.

Comment: In wait for a real answer from someone in the know: But the database rules are not available to the user for sure. It might be confusing with javascript both at frontend and backend, but all the stuff you deploy to firebase is not visible to everyone (server-side javascript), and I'm sure even the app creator will have a hard time trying to change the rules during runtime (i don't think it's possible).

Comment: @ippi Did you see the answer? Would that work?

Comment: One quick peek at the repo linked after the video I would assume only the files in the public-folder is available to the end-user. And anything else - database-rules included - is never in any danger of being shown or tampered with. I think that once you `firebase deploy` the database-rules are set in stone until your next deploy.

Comment: Never ever trust user input.

Comment: @JulianSoto Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I suppose that you do not want the player cheat, then don't check the answer result on the client-side.

Comment: Yeah, I just need help on how to run it on server side or whatever. I'm hoping to do this in JS only

Comment: @JulianSoto sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: @SheshankS. Node.js could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to put the logic that deals with the database in backend code that can't be tampered with.  Cloud Functions is the typical choice for that, if you're already working with Firebase.

At I/O 2017 [I gave a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWj6dxfN63g) about writing a turn based game that's immune to cheating by putting all the core logic on the backend with Cloud Functions.  The details are slightly out of date, but the principles remain the same.

Comment: First of all, this is pretty cool; getting an answer from someone who has gave a talk on something like this and works from on the firebase team, so thanks for that :) I have one more question, could you point me to an article of some sort that could teach me more about cloud functions, and how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Also, do I need to change the database rules? Thanks again for answering my question.

Comment: You're welcome!  I think if you watch the video, you'll have all the resources you need to know to continue.  If you have a specific question about your implementation, that would be another question to ask.

Comment: One more small thing, it isn't really related to this, but this is my first positively voted question in a while (I deleted negative questions), is this question okay? As in did I explain it and stuff well? I'm pretty new to the community, been using StackOverflow for only the past week.